# AngularJS - ngClick doesn't work / getAll() function undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Consider I'm new to Angular and this gives me a tough time. I've been trying different approaches and codes from

So I have simple view that gets/adds data from database through WEBapi.

3 questions:

1/ how come IE doesn't pass the data to view here? 
2/ what do I do wrong considering CHROME that the SUBMIT doesn't work?
3/ what is the best approach here to make it work on both browsers?

I can't figure out what's wrong. Chrome console doesn't find errors, but ngclick doesn't submit form.

[image]

On the other hand IE doesn't show the data in the list and shows error in the console.

[image]

As far as WEBapi is considered it works (tested it through both browsers and fiddler).

index.html

```
@{    Layout = null; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>MobilePostService Client Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/App/module.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/App/controller.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/App/service.js")



    <style>
        table, tr, td, th {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>



<body ng-app="APIModule" ng-controller="APIController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>CITY</th>
                    <th>STREET</th>
                    <th>POSTAL CODE</th>
                    <th>PHONE NR</th>
                    <th>EMAIL</th>
                    <th>REGISTRATION DATE</th>




                </tr>
                <tbody data-ng-repeat="par in parcel">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{par.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{par.City}}</td>
                        <td>{{par.Street}}</td>
                        <td>{{par.PostalCode}}</td>
                        <td>{{par.Phone}}</td>
                        <td>{{par.Email}}</td>
                        <td>{{par.RegistrationDate}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            @*<br /> <input type="button" ng-click="/new" value="Nowa paczka" />*@
            @*<a href="/">NOWA PACZKA</a>*@
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <form ng-submit="addParcel()">
              <table>
                  <tr>      <td>Name</td>      <td colspan=2><input type="text" ng-model="Name" /></td>    </tr>
                  <tr>      <td>City</td>      <td colspan=2><input type="text" ng-model="City" /></td>    </tr>
                  <tr>      <td>Street</td>     <td colspan=2><input type="text" ng-model="Street" /></td>    </tr>
                  <tr>      <td>PostalCode</td> <td colspan=2><input type="text" ng-model="PostalCode" /></td>    </tr>
                  <tr>      <td>Phone</td>      <td colspan=2><input type="text" ng-model="Phone" /></td>    </tr>
                  <tr>      <td>Email</td>      <td colspan=2><input type="text" ng-model="Email" /></td>    </tr>
                  <!--<tr>      <td>RegistrationDate</td>      <td colspan=2><input type="text" ng-model="parcel.RegistrationDate" /></td>    </tr>-->
                  @*<tr>      <td>Submit</td>      <td colspan=2><input type="click" id="submit" value="Submit"/></td>    </tr>*@

              </table>
              <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>



        </div>
    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

module.js (pushed all the code from other .js here)

```
var app;
(function () {
    app = angular.module("APIModule", []);

    app.service("APIService", function ($http) {

        this.getParcels = function () {


            //nalezt zmienic urlBase na biezacy z wyszukiwarki
            var urlBase = 'http://localhost:1797/api';
            return $http.get(urlBase + '/webapi');
        }

        this.saveParcel = function (par) {
            var urlBase = 'http://localhost:1797/api';
            return $http.post(urlBase + '/webapi', par);
        }
    });
    app.controller("APIController", function ($scope, APIService) {


        getAll();

        $scope.getAll = function () {
            var servCall = APIService.getParcels();

            servCall.then(function (d) {
                $scope.parcel = d.data;
            });
        };

        $scope.addParcel = function () {

            var parcel = {
                Name: $scope.Name,
                PostalCode: $scope.PostalCode,
                City: $scope.City,
                Phone: $scope.Phone,
                Email: $scope.Email,
                Street: $scope.Street,
                RegistrationDate: new Date()
            };

            var saveParcel = APIService.saveParcel(parcel);

            saveParcel.then(function (d, $scope) {
                //tutaj zwracam 
                $scope.getAll();
            });
        };


    });

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAll` is certainly undefined. You are calling it from your controller, but not prefixing it with `$scope`. So you are trying to call a function called `getAll` in the global namespace that does not exist. Do this instead:

```
getAll();

$scope.getAll = getAll;
function getAll() {
  ...
}
```

This way you can call it with or without the `$scope` prefix.

Also this is wrong:

```
var saveParcel = APIService.saveParcel(parcel);

saveParcel.then(function (d, $scope) {
  //tutaj zwracam 
  $scope.getAll();
});
```

There is no reason to have `$scope` as one of the callback parameters. By doing this you are overwriting the `$scope` variable of your controller. Since this callback parameter has no method `getAll`, you will once more get the undefined error. You don't really need the `d` variable either. So why include it? It should be like this:

```
var saveParcel = APIService.saveParcel(parcel);

saveParcel.then(function () {
  //tutaj zwracam 
  $scope.getAll();
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! worked perfectly :) perhaps you have some tutorial or materials in mind that explain best $scope ?